# System.Environment replacement in windows store apps?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, uwp

I am porting some c# library to UWP. It uses `System.Environment`. But It is no longer present if you are developing for Universal Windows Platform.

I need to replace

```
Environment.SystemDirectory

Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH")

Environment.OSVersion.Platform

Environment.Is64BitProcess
```

I tried to search but was not able to find anything.
For Environment Variables [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/42116c4d-c9ee-4ffa-a0c9-4d8b8a0b304c/environment-variables-in-a-store-app?forum=winappswithcsharp) post says it is not possible until system provides an api since a windows store app runs in a sandbox.

How can we get these properties in a windows store app?

Comment: Why the downvote ??

Comment: What are those features needed for? It is likely they are not meaningful for whatever you need to do in UWP.

Comment: I am making zmq compatible for UWP as I have used ZMQ in android and ios which was not much of a task. I have an existing code that I need to builkd as a portable class library. I don't want to exclude anything in the code unless there is no replacement for it.

Answer (score 2):

You can indirectly get OS Versions from the [AnalyticsInfo.VersionInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.profile.analyticsinfo.versioninfo.aspx) class and current architecture from the [packageId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows.applicationmodel.packageid). Here is [a good article](https://www.suchan.cz/2015/08/uwp-quick-tip-getting-device-os-and-app-info/) with code sample.

I think there is no way for UWP apps to get path to System directory or environment variables as these are out of security limitations for UWP apps. However some of environment variable can be acquired thru specific classes like User or NetworkInformation.